# Linq - Using array in Lambda expression to fetch multiple records

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Im not sure wether this is possible or not. I'd like to create an array (or list/dictionary) containing some simple id's and the use the array (or whatever) in a lambda expression.

The example below should return the UserId's 15850 and 15858

```
DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();    
int[] userIds = {15850, 15858};
var users = db.tblUsers.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(userIds));
```

Possible or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible, and will translate into a SQL `WHERE IN (...)` statement, but it is written kind of backwards in linq:

```
DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();    
int[] userIds = {15850, 15858};
var users = db.tblUsers.Where(x => userIds.Contains(x.UserId));
```